# Using dependancy injection with protocols for iOS framework classes

Tags: ios, swift

This is the beginning of my class:

```
class RoomMonitor: NSObject {

  private var locationManager: CLLocationManager
  private var building: BuildingProtocol
  private var beacons: BeaconsProtocol

  init (thisBuilding:BuildingProtocol, thisLocationManager:CLLocationManager, theseBeacons:BeaconsProtocol) {
    building = thisBuilding
    locationManager = thisLocationManager
    beacons = theseBeacons
```

I want to use a protocol for the second parameter type instead of `CLLocationManager`. I've tried declaring a protocol for the bits I need:

```
protocol LocationManagerProtocol {
  func respondsToSelector(selector:Selector) -> Bool
  func requestAlwaysAuthorization()
  func startMonitoringForRegion(region:CLBeaconRegion)
  func startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region:CLBeaconRegion)
  func startUpdatingLocation()
  var delegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate { set get }
}
```

and using `thisLocationManager:LocationManagerProtocol` as the parameter declaration but it says `CLLocationManager` doesn't conform to the `LocationManagerProtocol`. I've also tried using extension to add the protocol but it says the methods are public and I'm not allowed to use public in a protocol.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I understand access control (not sure when it was added to Swift but I'm using Swift 2 beta in Xcode 7 beta 3) all I had to do was insert "public" before "protocol". The default was "internal protocol" and you can't include public items in an internal protocol.

.. and used the extension

> extension CLLocationManager:LocationManagerProtocol {    }

and I removed the delegate from the protocol as that was a separate problem